# Amazon EC2 .NET API, launch random instance

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have the following question...I wonder if there is some methods on the EC2 .NET API that allow me to list all the available AMIs(like in the web interface) in a given region. At least their id's. I want to set up a random image and this is the only missed piece from the puzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be simple. Here is a code excerpt that will return all AMIs in the available or pending state (add your own filters and surrounding `try/catch` block):

```
AmazonEC2 ec2 = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonEC2Client(
    "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY",
    "YOUR_SECRET_KEY"
    );

DescribeImagesRequest request = new DescribeImagesRequest();
request.WithFilter(new Filter[] {
    new Filter().WithName("state").WithValue("available", "pending")});
DescribeImagesResponse ec2Response = ec2.DescribeImages(request);
```

This query will bring all public AND private AMIs. Since the results in the result set contain the attribute which says whether an instance is public or private (e.g. `<Visibility>Private</Visibility>`).

If you want only your own AMIs, add the `.WithOwner("YOUR_AMAZON_ID")` to your filter definition. For example:

```
request.WithFilter(new Filter[] {
    new Filter().WithName("state").WithValue("available", pending")})
    .WithOwner("YOUR_AMAZON_ID");
```

or

```
request.WithOwner("YOUR_AMAZON_ID");
```

For further reference, please see the [AWS SDK for .NET Documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/Index.html). On the tree on the left, select Amazon/Amazon.EC2.Model/DescribeImagesRequest Class.
Also, the [DescribeImages API Reference](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeImages.html) contains the name and possible values of every `Filter` you can use in this request.

PS: Since you are explicitly talking about regions, and AMIs do not have a region associated to them, it might be possible that you are talking about Instances instead. In this case, there is a similar request called `DescribeInstances`. Find more details about it [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/Index.html) (Amazon/Amazon.EC2.Model/DescribeInstancesRequest Class) and [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeInstances.html).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your help is very useful...I will give it a try and come back :)